# Find data in an array above certain percentile for consective days

Tags: matlab, descriptive-statistics, quantiles

I have a time series for 10 years of observations. i want to find number of events when the values are above 90th and 80th percentile for consecutive three days.Further i need to find the length of each events in days when the data is above given percentile.